# Flutter container to position bottom right

Tags: flutter, flutter-container

I have a flutter container (Trending text in violet) which is positioned **top left** right now. I am wondering what code changes i should do to position the container **bottom right** ?

```
                     Container(
                        height: 25.0,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(12.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Shimmer.fromColors(
                          baseColor: Colors.white60,
                          highlightColor: Colors.white,
                          period: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                          child: Text(
                            'Trending',
                            maxLines: 1,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                              fontSize: 13.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
```

Current view

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is that you would need to adapt your border radius for the right size (invert them).

The second one is that you should modify the Stack widget above this Container and set its alignment property to Alignment. topRight !

Comment: Thanks. What should i do if i want to keep both ?

Comment: Copy paste it in your stack’ children list argument (the whole container widget)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your image and text in a `Stack` and set the wanted alignment.

```
Stack(
alignment: Alignment.topRight,
children: <Widget>[
 ...
 ],
)
```